# The error when android virtual machine runs under in ubuntu system

Tags: android, ubuntu

There is an error when android virtual machine runs under in ubuntu system.

What is the problem?

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'test'
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u have 64 bit then install ia32-libs package.
In Terminal Execute below command:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

[reference](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html#troubleshooting)